# How to extract characters between first and second underscores of filenames and count such files in Linux folder?

Tags: shell, python, perl, bash-scripting

I would like to extract characters between first and second underscores of filenames in a folder and count such type of files present in it.

The folder contains files in a particular format such as:

```
2305195303310_ABC_A08_1378408840043.hl7

2305195303310_ABC_A08_1378408840043.hl7
Q37984932T467566261_DEF_R03_1378825633215.hl7
37982442T467537201_DEF_R03_1378823455384.hl7
37982442T467537201_MNO_R03_1378823455384.hl7
2305195303310_ABC_A08_1378408840053.hl7
Q37984932T467566261_DEF_R03_1378825633215.hl7
37982442T467537201_MNO_R03_1378823455384.hl7
```

And so on…

The output of the script should give me result as:

```
ABC 3
DEF 3
MNO 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | cut -d_ -f2 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Could you add more description to your answer? Share your knowledge, not just give a command.

Comment: Art does not reproduce what we see; rather, it makes us see.

Comment: 'ls | cut -d_ -f2 | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print$2" "$1}' gives the list as the op intended

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the classic *nix way, by stringing small commands together. First, find the files of interest, for this you can use shell [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html):

```
for i in *_*_*; do echo "$i"; done
```

That command will print all files in the current directory whose name contains two underscores. To extract the string between those underscores, you could use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut), telling it to use `_` as the field delimiter and to print the 2nd field:

```
cut -d '_' -f 2
```

Piping the first command through the second will print the strings you are interested in but it will also print an empty line for those cases where there is no character between the underscores (`foo__bar` for example). You can filter those out using `grep .` which will only print lines that contain at least one character (including whitespace). Finally, you can count by passing the output through [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) and [`uniq -c`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq).

Putting it all together gives you:

```
$ for i in *_*_*; do echo "$i" | cut -d '_' -f 2 ; done | 
   grep . | sort | uniq -c

  3 ABC
  2 DEF
  1 MNO
```

If you really want the number to be on the other side, you could use `awk`:

```
$ for i in *_*_*; do echo "$i" | cut -d '_' -f 2 ; done | 
   grep . | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'

ABC 3
DEF 2
MNO 1
```

Comment: No need to call `echo` for everything; just do `ls *_*_* | ...`; instead of grep and sort and uniq, count lines with something in an associative array in awk directly: `ls *_*_* | cut -d_ -f2 | awk '/./ { count[$1]++; } END {for (f in count) { print f, count[f]; } }'` (note: you can do the cut part in awk as well, of course, but for a comment field that's too awkward (pun unavoidable)).

Comment: @Gabe that is a [very bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), parsing `ls` should always be avoided and breaks on many things, first and foremost names containing spaces. Apart from that, using coreutils is i) faster and ii) more portable than implementing gawk and (`ls` is notoriously non-portable between systems and locales) iii) more faithful to the *nix way. Of course you can do it with a script but why when you have compiled executables that can do it for you?

Comment: I disagree. Or rather, I agree that dealing with filenames is something best not done in the shell **at all** - given that there are exactly two byte values (NUL and slash) that aren't potentially parts of file names, the shell utilities simply aren't equipped to deal with all of the weird cases (newlines will break both our suggestions). That said, `/bin/ls -1 *_*_*` will be no worse than the for loop (which will fork/exec a pipeline for every single file, uselessly, instead of once). Your portability comment is a red herring: that awk code is portable across POSIX.

Comment: @Gabe for the awk comment I was thinking more about busybox and embedded systems that are very likely not to have awk. I'm willing to bet that the for loop will be faster than implementing a gawk solution but I'll have to test that :). You're right about `ls -1` being equivalent, I was thinking of `ls` alone.

Comment: No contest. `time bash -c 'for i in a_b_c d_e_f aa_b_c dd_e_f ; do echo "$i" | cut -d_ -f2 ; done | grep . | sort | uniq -c'` vs `time bash -c 'printf "%s\\n" a_b_c d_e_f aa_b_c dd_e_f | cut -d_ -f2 | awk '\''/./ { count[$1]++; } END {for (f in count) { print f, count[f]; } }'\'` - more files will just make the iteration slower. On the workstation, the loop takes 15ms vs 8 for a single pipe; macbook takes 24 vs 12.

Comment: @Gabe I stand corrected, I'll update the answer when I get the chance, thanks. In the meantime, you might want to check out [unix.se] we _live_ for this kind of constructive pedantry over there :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job using Perl.

```perl
perl -aE '/^[^_]+_\K[^_]+/ && $h{$&}++}{say$_," ",$h{$_} for sort keys %h' file
ABC 3
DEF 3
MNO 2
```

**Explanation:**

```perl
perl -aE                # invoque Perl compiler with autosplit lines
/^[^_]+_\K[^_]+/        # match non _ characters after the first _
 &&                     # execute the next command if a match is found
$h{$&}++}               # increment a counter for each match founded
{say$_," ",$h{$_}       # finally print each match and the counter associated
for sort keys %h        # for each sorted matches
```